# Posting form-data and binary data through AWS API Gateway

Tags: post, base64, binaryfiles, multipartform-data, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to POST "mutlipart\form-data" to my EC2 instance through AWS API Gateway, but I couldn't find a way to this. There is a way to post data using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and Mapping Tamplate to convert it to JSON but still posting a binary data like an image file is missing I guess. Is there anything I'm missing ?

EDIT:

I have found another way:

I convert the image to base64 string then POST it as with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". By this way I'm sending whole image as string. After I got the message I can convert it back to image in PHP. Only down side of this I could find is when I convert image to base64 its size gets a bit bigger. Other than that, I couldnt find any other downside. If there is could you please share with me ?

Comment: You can try uploading binary data separately to S3 via AJAX. That should fix your problem.

Comment: @kixorz, there are multiple reason why people stick to API Gateway, and not sending data directly to S3. In my case, I need the API to be simple and user must have API-Key to make a call to an endpoint. API Gateway simplifies that for me.

Comment: I know this, but for the time being you need to find a workaround. S3 is a decent solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Api Gateway team here.

<s>Binary data isn't supported at the moment, but it's on our backlog. Several customers have requested this.</s>

Some customers have had success using the base64 util in the mapping templates which may get it working for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

Other than that you'll have to wait for official support.

**Edit**

[Binary support is finally here!!](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/)