# S3 Form File Upload via AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to upload a file from a web form to S3 through API Gateway? The 'method request' and 'integration request' has no way to configure the file upload. Or there is and I am missing it?

Comment: Realted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645205/how-to-upload-file-to-lambda-function-or-api-gateway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It's possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/) to POST binary file uploads through `API Gateway`. However the binary data is converted to `base64` encoded text. This has implications on memory consumption and processing the data. Data has to be processed as a buffer not as a stream.

See the following questions [API Gateway file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645205/how-to-upload-file-to-lambda-function-or-api-gateway) and [API Gateway binary data form POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364996/posting-form-data-and-binary-data-through-aws-api-gateway).

Comment: please check    https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/

Comment: thanks for the heads up, this approach is still not universally suitable for file uploads

Comment: Can i send audio to s3 via amazon api gateway?

Comment: @Sabreena you can send any content through it, but I'd recommend doing direct S3 upload instead