# Dynamically created JPG image using AWS Lambda service

Tags: dynamic, flask, jpeg, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a dynamically created graph as a JPG file that I could use in Alexa Skill standard cards as part of response. The following code creates a JPG image when I run it locally on my computer, when using browser with URL "http://localhost:5000/image.jpg".

```
from flask import send_file
from flask import Flask
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


def serve_pil_image(pil_img):
    img_io = BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')

@app.route('/image.jpg')
def serve_img():
    size = (128,128)
    background = (128,128,55)
    xy = [(0,0),(10,10),(20,20),(30,12),(50,50),(70,9),(90,70)]

    img = Image.new('RGB',size,background)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.line(xy, fill=128, width=5)
    return serve_pil_image(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I deploy the same code to AWS Lambda service using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) I am getting the following error message (from CloudWatch logs):

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Is there some configuration option to fix this problem? I haven't found any so far.

Comment: What version of Python are you using locally?

Comment: @dirn Python 2.7.10

Comment: Looks like the problem is that AWS Api Gateway doesn't support binary output data, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364996/posting-form-data-and-binary-data-through-aws-api-gateway)

Answer (score 1):

[Binary Support is finally here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/)!  You should look at it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve binary data (in this case Base64 images) through API Gateway, you need to set the following:

1. In the **Method Response** of your method
   Set `Content-Type` as `image/jpeg` in HTTP 200 Status Response
   Header
2. In the **Integration Response** of your method
   Set `Content-Type` as `'image/jpeg'` in Header Mappings. **Mind the quotes!**
3. With the AWS CLI, set `contentHandling` attribute to `CONVERT_TO_BINARY`on your Integration Response

Check to entire process in this great step-by step guide:     https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434295/720665
*(example is for a base64 encoded png image, but the gist of it is the same)*